# Функция которая динамически генерирует результат

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

Всем привет!

Есть задача создать функцию которая будет способна генерировать массив результатов, при этом что бы поддерживался TypeScript

Вот текущая реализация

```
    const call = <ArgumentsType extends any[], ReturnType>(
    functionToCall: (...args: ArgumentsType) => ReturnType, ...args: ArgumentsType[]
): ReturnType[] => {
    return args.map((args) => functionToCall(...args));
}
  
const testFunc = <T = any>({arg}: {arg: T}) => {
    console.log(arg);
}
  
const testFunc2 = <T extends any = any>(...arg: T[]) => {
    const result = arg;
    return result;
}
  
call(testFunc, 
    [{arg: 'test'}],
    [{arg: 1}],
    [{arg: null}],
    [{arg: true}]
)
  
const result2 = call(testFunc2, 
    ['string'],
    [null],
    [2],
    [true]
)


export default {};
```

Данная реализация работает хорошо до тех пор пока не появляются разные типы данных у аргумента функции

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно как то правильно описать подобное поведение в TypeScript? Или это вовсе не поддерживается в TypeScript?

Заранее всем спасибо за ответы

Comment: добавь [mcve] который можно запустить и увидеть проблему.

Comment: Обновил основной вопрос

Comment: `...args: [ ...args: ArgumentsType][]` что ты тут пытался сделать? Почему не просто `...args: ArgumentsType[]`

Comment: Действительно заигрался, поправил как вы написали и предыдущий пример решился,

описал чуть более сложный пример и выложил в общем вопросе